# App Review on Facebook - Private Software that may scale up in the future

Tags: facebook, oauth-2.0

So we've developed a Facebook App (and similar apps on Twitter and Instagram) that allow users to post and read content using an external system. We'll sell this integration directly to our clients, so it's a **private** application.

Basically the user will see a very simple page with a button "Log in to Facebook" and a disclaimer regarding the authorization (we'll use some query params fixed in the url, depending on the client). The client authorize us and we capture the access tokens.

To submit the app review, though, we have to explicitly give a test user to the reviewers, but that's not really possible because the real "action" happens within the integrated systems, NOT within the app itself. And those systems are not public (they **shouldn't** be).

So just to be clear: our app is basically a very simple "Facebook login" that we use to get tokens, generated by specific clients authorization. It's not going to be published anywhere.

Until we have around 5 to 10 clients we can add the specific users in our app as Testers/Admins/etc, but what if we scale up? Say we have 20 clients. How are we supposed to get our app to be "live"?

To follow the app review steps we would have to create some users in our local systems (we have some dev environments), open them to the internet so the reviewers can log in and see how it actually works? Is that it?

*(btw I'm asking this because our app review was rejected twice and I want to make sure I'm submitting everything they ask this time).*

Thanks :)

Comment: well, you only have 2 options: add users to your app (usually as tester) or go through review. of course facebook needs to access the app if you want to go through review...that should be obvious.

Comment: thanks for your reply. yeah I agree but the app itself is just to generate an access token (using manage_pages and publish_pages scopes), our system (that use those tokens) is not published. so basically the reviewer will click on "Login" (that login page can be on internet) and he will see a message "token generated successfully". would that be enough, though? that ofc after seeing the facebook popup with the requested scopes.

Comment: no, the reviewer needs to see how you use the permissions. else, the whole review system would be pretty pointless.

Comment: why not just create a test user (in the app settings) and let facebook use/test your tool?

Comment: like I said our "tool" is not published by nature (maybe we have to change that yeah). so the problem is that the facebook login is not used to log in into the system directly (would be easier if it was). this facebook integration is used in a couple of pages inside our CRM system. so the only solution I see here is to create a specific CRM account linked to a FB test user and publish our CRM on the internet

Comment: we didn't want to go through that, though. at first I thought we could publish the login page but show the system itself in the screencast. but that doesn't seem to be enough. thanks anyway :)

Comment: with only 20 clients, why not just add them as tester anyway?

Comment: if we don't submit the app review but put our app in live mode, can we get the authorizations by adding specific users? I mean, in development mode only registered test users see the content posted using publish_pages auth.

Comment: should be no problem

Comment: alright, I will try that, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the [Login Review FAQ](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review/faqs) answers most of your questions. The key point:

> Our review team will actually test how your app uses each permission on every platform you have listed in the settings section of your app.... You'll need to explain exactly how to test each permission or feature in your app so that we can make sure it works and follows our policies. We can't approve your app if we can't fully test how it integrates with Facebook.

In other words, it's not enough to just allow them to log in to your app, you have to expose all Facebook-related features to the reviewer.

*To follow the app review steps we would have to create some users in our local systems (we have some dev environments), open them to the internet so the reviewers can log in and see how it actually works? Is that it?*

Yes, though I'm not sure what you mean by "open them to the internet". You should be able to create a test user on your local system and link that account to a test Facebook user. Then you can have the Facebook reviewer use that test account for their review. (From the FAQ: "In the Items in Review section, you'll see a Test User (optional) section that allows you to type the name of the user you wish to be used in your review.")

Comment: Yes that makes sense, I've been reading all the docs again to make sure I'm doing the right thing. By "open" I mean exposing our softwares on the internet. They are meant to be local only (it's an on premise solution). The Facebook integration is a small part of a huge system, so we are working on exposing only the required pages/areas to the reviewers. And it's actually not trivial to just create a new CRM account and link that to a test FB user. We basically would have to recreate a huge ammount of objects and configurations, that's the hard part.

Comment: I mean, each client for us is basically a new 'on premise system', so we have our dev environment configured using a specific fake account on FB (with fanpages and etc). To link that specific environment to a NEW FB test user we'd have to move around a bunch of basically hard coded stuff, delete objects and etc. So that's why it'd be way easier to just expose the login and record the integration usage on the screencast, not exposing everything. But thanks for your reply, you got the point there :)

Comment: @vitorrrr: I see what you're saying, that does sound like a pain. I don't see any way around it unless you can bypass review entirely

Comment: yeah, we will stick with the roles registration for a while, but now we know exactly what we a have to do :) ty